# Números Primos - function / array

Tags: javascript

Boa noite,
alguém poderia me ajudar a entender como funciona a variável **quantidadeDeDivisores** no código abaixo? Sei que ela está armazenando os números primos, mas queria saber se os números são armazenados um de cada vez ou todos de uma vez, como um array?

```
 var n = 10;

 function buscaNumeroPrimos(n) {

  var numerosPrimos = [];

  for (var i = 2; i < n; i++){   //Armazenou os números de 2 a 9
     var quantidadeDeDivisores = 0; 

     for(var b = 2; b < i; b++) { //Armazenou os números de 2 a 9
        if (i % b == 0) {
           quantidadeDeDivisores ++;
        }
     }

     if (quantidadeDeDivisores % i == 0) {
        numerosPrimos.push(i);
     }

  }

return numerosPrimos;
}
```

Comment: "...Sei que ela está armazenando os números primos...", não! `quantidadeDeDivisores` não está armazenando os números primos, na verdade é um contador usado para somar um a um o  número de divisores de `i` menores que `i`. Funciona da seguinte forma, `b` varia de `2` até `i` a cada variação de `b` é feito um teste `i % b == 0` se o resto de `i` dividido por `b` for `0` implica que `b` é um divisor de `i` e então é adicionado `1`  `quantidadeDeDivisores`. Ao final da iteração se `quantidadeDeDivisores` for diferente de zero significa que o número não é primo.

Comment: Muito obrigado Augusto.

Answer (score 0):

Quem está armazenando os números primos é o método `push()`

O método `push()` adiciona um ou mais elementos ao final de um array e retorna o novo comprimento desse array.

O simbolo do operador `%` é chamado de operador de módulo. O resultado de uma operação com esse operador gera resto da divisão de dois valores. Se o resto for zero, então o primeiro valor pode ser dividido exatamente pelo segundo.

A aritmética é útil para aquelas ocasiões em que você deseja saber se um número é divisível perfeitamente por outro

A variável `quantidadeDeDivisores` é uma variável que quantifica o números de divisores de `i` por `b` cujo resto é zero `0`

Execute o código abaixo clicando em Executar no final desta resposta e observe que quando a variável `quantidadeDeDivisores` é zero significa ser um numero primo e é armazenado no array.

```js
 function buscaNumeroPrimos(n) {

  var numerosPrimos = [];

  for (var i = 2; i < n; i++){   //Armazenou os números de 2 a 9
     var quantidadeDeDivisores = 0; 
     
     var explica = (" Para i = " + i);
     
     for(var b = 2; b < i; b++) { //Armazenou os números de 2 a 9     
        explica += (" ; b = " + b);
        //se o resto dessa divisão for 0 é um divisor e incrementa quantidadeDeDivisores
        if (i % b == 0) {
           quantidadeDeDivisores ++;
        }

     }
        console.log(" ");
        explica +=(" quantidadeDeDivisores = " + quantidadeDeDivisores);
     
 console.log(explica);
 
     //if (quantidadeDeDivisores  == 0) {
     if (quantidadeDeDivisores % i == 0) {
     
        numerosPrimos.push(i);
        console.log(numerosPrimos);
        
     }

  }

return numerosPrimos;

}

buscaNumeroPrimos(20);
```